# Query database for value changes at arbitrary periods of time

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

Let's say that I have N family members. At any time I may decide to change my own name and the same goes for any other member of my family. Moreover, there is no limit regarding the amount of times one is allowed to change name.

For every name change, I store in a Cassandra table (note that this problem may be orthogonal to the DB technology) the entry `<familyMemberUniqueId,newName,timeStamp>`. The way we model this or any other table in our database is open to suggestions.

My problem arises when I try to query my database for:

- What were the names of each family member at an arbitrary time interval?
- Which members of my family had a specific name at an arbitrary time interval?

If I changed my name multiple times within the specified time interval, I should return the last change. This problem becomes particularly hard to solve when no changes were performed during the specified interval, because a straightforward query would not return any results.

Therefore, my question is how can I model my database and/or queries to address this problem?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Is multiple family posible ? If yes then where is the family id ?

Comment: Does it help? If so, then we can have multiple families